# Order by name and by most popular title - Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have this query

```
select movie_name, user_name
from movie natural join movie_queue natural join users
group by (movie_name, user_name)
order by movie_name;
```

That drops a list similar to the one below:

```
 MOVIE_NAME                                              USER_NAME              
------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              Cris                     
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              Elizabeth                
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              John                     
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              Mary                     
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              Peter                    
Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull      Elizabeth                
Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull      John                     
Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull      Mary                     
Jurassic Park                                           Elizabeth                
Jurassic Park                                           John                     
Jurassic Park                                           Mary                     
Jurassic Park                                           Peter                    
Signs                                                   Elizabeth                
The Sixth Sense                                         Mary                     
Unbreakable                                             John                     
Unbreakable                                             Mary                     
Unbreakable                                             Peter                    
War of the Worlds                                       Elizabeth                
War of the Worlds                                       John                     
War of the Worlds                                       Mary                     
War of the Worlds                                       Peter
```

**The Question is how do I order by row popularity and by movie_name ?**
I am currently ordering the list by movie_name, but I also want to order them from the 
most popular movie to the less popular movie.

**The desired result:**

As a result, 
"E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial" rows should appear first because it appears more times on the table,  and "The Sixth Sense" should appear last, right after "Signs". Because both last movies appear only 1 time, but S goes before T.

I tried adding this:
order by count(movie_name), movie_name;

But I still don't get the result I want. 
At the end movies should be organized like this

**This is how I want them to be organized: From more popular to less popular, and in alphabetical order**

```
 MOVIE_NAME                                              USER_NAME              
------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              Cris                     
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              Elizabeth                
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              John                     
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              Mary                     
E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial                              Peter  
Jurassic Park                                           Elizabeth                
Jurassic Park                                           John                     
Jurassic Park                                           Mary                     
Jurassic Park                                           Peter 
War of the Worlds                                       Elizabeth                
War of the Worlds                                       John                     
War of the Worlds                                       Mary                     
War of the Worlds                                       Peter   
Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull      Elizabeth                
Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull      John                     
Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull      Mary  
Unbreakable                                             John                     
Unbreakable                                             Mary                     
Unbreakable                                             Peter 
Signs                                                   Elizabeth                
The Sixth Sense                                         Mary
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify multiple columns for the order by clause. Moreover, you can even mix the desc, asc.

In your case it would be something like:

```
select movie_name, user_name, count(movie_name) popularity 
from movie natural join movie_queue natural join users
group by (movie_name, user_name)
order by popularity, movie_name;
```

see also: http://psoug.org/reference/orderby.html

Comment: @Burhan, thanks!, I understand I can have multiple columns, I tried count(movie_name) as a second column but I still don't get the result I want. I need it to put the movies that are more popular first (popularity is bases on having more rows).

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
select movie_name, user_name
from movie natural join movie_queue natural join users
order by count(*) over (partition by movie_name) ,movie_name;
```